# Audio decoding delay when changing the audio language

Tags: audio, gstreamer

My gstreamer Pipeline is like this

**Approach1**

```
                        --------------input-selector->Queue->AduioParser->AudioSink
                       |
Souphttpsrc->tsdemux-->|
                       |
                       --------------- Queue->videoParser->videoSink
```

In this approach 1, there is a delay in audio decoding when I toggle between various audio language.

**Approach2**

```
                                  ------ input-selector-> Queue->AduioParser->AudioSink
                                  |
Souphttpsrc->tsdemux---multiqueue>|
                                  |
                                  ------- Queue->videoParser->VideoSink
```

But there is no delay is observed in approach2.

*Can anyone please explain the reason behind this ? what is the specialty of multiqueue here?*

Comment: How is the tsdemux linked to input-selector? All audio outputs go to it? Same with the output from multiqueue?

Comment: @thiagoss yes, all the audio outputs of tsdemux or multiqueue will go to input-selector.